# tar command failing with "Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive"

Tags: tar

I just can't understand what is the mistake with the following tar command that complains `tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive`

```
tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f 107668.tar -C /home/psham/projects/data_dump/2021/1076data
```

The folder `/home/psham/projects/data_dump/2021/1076data` exists & has files in it.

Please could a second pair of eyes help me out of this?

Comment: this might be a better question for [su]

Comment: Try to put . in the end of the command, the -C will tell to tar to change its folder before starting, my guess is that you didn't tell to tar which files to archive

Comment: @geckos Thanks a ton. Yes it was the . (dot) that was missing. Please do post it in the answer section & I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a `.` in the end of the command.

The -C tell tar to change its directory before running but without specifying what to archive tar has no idea what to do.

You can read `tar cf foo.tar -C bar zar1 zar2` as: create an archive named foo.tar by going to bar folder and archiving zar1 and zar2 files.